# how to loop trough python json response object

Tags: python, json

i have an api call to stock market news that should return news within the last 7 days. Im trying to print all the data but when I run the program it doesn't show anything. just blank.  How do I loop trough all the values and print all the data within the object? here is the response. I need to print the date  , text , sentiment and tickers.
Thanks for the help

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Attractively-Priced Apple Has Phenomenal Dividend Growth Potential",
            "text": "Apple offers investors tremendous capital appreciation and dividend growth potential, in our view. The company is a true financial powerhouse. Initial reports indicate Apple's new iPhone 12 offering, its first-ever 5G-capable smartphone, is selling well. We expect sentiment to remain positive.",
            "source_name": "Seeking Alpha",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 22:56:54 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "dividend"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Positive",
            "type": "Article",
            "tickers": [
                "AAPL"
            ]
        },
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Square's Jack Dorsey reportedly looking to acquire Jay-Z's Tidal",
            "text": "CNBC's Kate Rooney reports on Square's plans to be a 'mega-app,' by launching a clothing line and potentially buying Tidal, a music service owned by Jay-Z.",
            "source_name": "CNBC Television",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:48:13 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "CEO",
                "manda"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Positive",
            "type": "Video",
            "tickers": [
                "SQ"
            ]
        },
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Apple reportedly has plans for an electric car: Investors will see limited earnings impact: Analyst",
            "text": "Yahoo Finance's Brian Sozzi breaks down the note from Goldman Sachs analyst Rod Hall about Apple's plans to produce an electric car. For 2020 election results please visit: Election results: https://www.yahoo.com/elections Subscribe to Yahoo Finance: About Yahoo Finance: At Yahoo Finance, you get free stock quotes, up-to-date news, portfolio management resources, international market data, social interaction and mortgage rates that help you manage your financial life.",
            "source_name": "Yahoo Finance",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:41:18 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "earnings",
                "product"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Neutral",
            "type": "Video",
            "tickers": [
                "AAPL"
            ]
        },
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Apple Partnering With Tesla Is Just First Step, Says Ives",
            "text": "Dec.24 -- Dan Ives of Wedbush says Apple partnering with Tesla to make a self-driving electric car would make sense. He appears on \"Bloomberg The Open.",
            "source_name": "Bloomberg Technology",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:28:20 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "product"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Neutral",
            "type": "Video",
            "tickers": [
                "AAPL"
            ]
        },
```

here is my code

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
import requests
import json
# Init
import winsound
import sqlite3
duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz


response = requests.get("https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1?tickers=AAPL,SQ,PLTR&items=50&date=last7days&token=myapikey")


def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text +' ff /n')



    for i in response:    

        jprint(response.json()['data'][i]['date'] +  '          title : ' + response.json()['data'][i]['title'] + " news " +  response.json()['data'][i]['text'] +  " sentiment " + response.json()['data'][i]['sentiment'] )
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown? What happens when you run it? Is there an error message?

Comment: nothing prints out

Comment: Is it on purpose that `jprint` calls itself? Or where is `jprint` supposed to be called?

Comment: You're _defining_ the `jprint()` function but it's never _called_.

Comment: if i do print instead of jprint it doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

don't you want to loop through data? data is the list, response is a dictionary, which has one key, data.

```
for i in response['data'] :
    ...
```

Comment: and how would i print the values ?

Comment: in my answer `i` is a poor name for  the variable, it should be `for news_article in response [`data`] :`, and then `print(news_article['sentiment']) `. you can also take @Nour-allah hussein s approach

Answer (score 0):

Based in your code, you should update the loop from

```
for i in response:
```

to

```
for i in range( len( response.json()['data'] )):
```

and your code will work as it is (after adjusting indentation)

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
import requests
import json
# Init
import winsound
import sqlite3
duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz


response = requests.get("https://stocknewsapi.com/api/v1?tickers=AAPL,SQ,PLTR&items=50&date=last7days&token=myapikey")


def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text +' ff /n')



for i in range( len( response.json()['data'] )):    

        jprint(response.json()['data'][i]['date'] +  '          title : ' + response.json()['data'][i]['title'] + " news " +  response.json()['data'][i]['text'] +  " sentiment " + response.json()['data'][i]['sentiment'] )
```

but you can make life more easy by

```
my_data=response.json()['data']
for i in range( len( my_data )):    

        jprint(my_data[i]['date'] +  '          title : ' +my_data[i]['title'] + " news " +  my_data[i]['text'] +  " sentiment " + my_data[i]['sentiment'] )
```

*your data and code json based example*

```
import json

def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text +' ff /n')


x = '''
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Attractively-Priced Apple Has Phenomenal Dividend Growth Potential",
            "text": "Apple offers investors tremendous capital appreciation and dividend growth potential, in our view. The company is a true financial powerhouse. Initial reports indicate Apple's new iPhone 12 offering, its first-ever 5G-capable smartphone, is selling well. We expect sentiment to remain positive.",
            "source_name": "Seeking Alpha",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 22:56:54 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "dividend"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Positive",
            "type": "Article",
            "tickers": [
                "AAPL"
            ]
        },
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Square's Jack Dorsey reportedly looking to acquire Jay-Z's Tidal",
            "text": "CNBC's Kate Rooney reports on Square's plans to be a 'mega-app,' by launching a clothing line and potentially buying Tidal, a music service owned by Jay-Z.",
            "source_name": "CNBC Television",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:48:13 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "CEO",
                "manda"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Positive",
            "type": "Video",
            "tickers": [
                "SQ"
            ]
        },
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Apple reportedly has plans for an electric car: Investors will see limited earnings impact: Analyst",
            "text": "Yahoo Finance's Brian Sozzi breaks down the note from Goldman Sachs analyst Rod Hall about Apple's plans to produce an electric car. For 2020 election results please visit: Election results: https://www.yahoo.com/elections Subscribe to Yahoo Finance: About Yahoo Finance: At Yahoo Finance, you get free stock quotes, up-to-date news, portfolio management resources, international market data, social interaction and mortgage rates that help you manage your financial life.",
            "source_name": "Yahoo Finance",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:41:18 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "earnings",
                "product"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Neutral",
            "type": "Video",
            "tickers": [
                "AAPL"
            ]
        },
        {
            "news_url": "",
            "image_url": "",
            "title": "Apple Partnering With Tesla Is Just First Step, Says Ives",
            "text": "Dec.24 -- Dan Ives of Wedbush says Apple partnering with Tesla to make a self-driving electric car would make sense. He appears on Bloomberg The Open.",
            "source_name": "Bloomberg Technology",
            "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:28:20 -0500",
            "topics": [
                "product"
            ],
            "sentiment": "Neutral",
            "type": "Video",
            "tickers": [
                "AAPL"
            ]
        }
            ]
        }
    '''
my_data = json.loads(x)

for i in range(len(my_data["data"])):
    jprint(my_data['data'][i]['date'] + '          title : ' + my_data['data'][i]['title'] + " news " +
           my_data['data'][i]['text'] + " sentiment " + my_data['data'][i]['sentiment'])
```

*Outpt*

```
"Thu, 24 Dec 2020 22:56:54 -0500          title : Attractively-Priced Apple Has Phenomenal Dividend Growth Potential news Apple offers investors tremendous capital appreciation and dividend growth potential, in our view. The company is a true financial powerhouse. Initial reports indicate Apple's new iPhone 12 offering, its first-ever 5G-capable smartphone, is selling well. We expect sentiment to remain positive. sentiment Positive" ff /n
"Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:48:13 -0500          title : Square's Jack Dorsey reportedly looking to acquire Jay-Z's Tidal news CNBC's Kate Rooney reports on Square's plans to be a 'mega-app,' by launching a clothing line and potentially buying Tidal, a music service owned by Jay-Z. sentiment Positive" ff /n
"Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:41:18 -0500          title : Apple reportedly has plans for an electric car: Investors will see limited earnings impact: Analyst news Yahoo Finance's Brian Sozzi breaks down the note from Goldman Sachs analyst Rod Hall about Apple's plans to produce an electric car. For 2020 election results please visit: Election results: https://www.yahoo.com/elections Subscribe to Yahoo Finance: About Yahoo Finance: At Yahoo Finance, you get free stock quotes, up-to-date news, portfolio management resources, international market data, social interaction and mortgage rates that help you manage your financial life. sentiment Neutral" ff /n
"Thu, 24 Dec 2020 12:28:20 -0500          title : Apple Partnering With Tesla Is Just First Step, Says Ives news Dec.24 -- Dan Ives of Wedbush says Apple partnering with Tesla to make a self-driving electric car would make sense. He appears on Bloomberg The Open. sentiment Neutral" ff /n
```